# How to return sprintf?

Tags: c

I was wondering If someone could let me know the best way to return a sprintf string.

So (I think) I understand why this isn't working at all, it's because once the function is run everything on the stack is destroyed so buffer is returning noting.

I have a couple of similar functions like the one below and I'm out of ideas on how I should go about returning the sprintf string. Should I malloc the buffer for every function?

```
const char* gradeCheck(double mark) {
    char buffer [100];
    if (mark > MAX_MARK || mark < MIN_MARK) {
        sprintf(buffer, "INVALID TYPE\n");
        return buffer;
    } else if (mark >= PASSING_MARK && mark <= MAX_MARK) {
        sprintf(buffer, "Student achieved %.2lf\n", mark);
        return buffer;
    } else {
        sprintf(buffer, "Student achieved %.2lf which means they failed ;(\n", mark);
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: `char buffer [100];` is declared local to `gradeCheck` and its memory is no longer valid after the function returns. Allocate `buffer`, e.g. `char *buffer = malloc (100 +1);` (and don't forget to validate the allocation succeeds -- or pass `buffer` as a parameter to the function)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you sir for the explanation, got it working. Have a great day!

Comment: (don't forget to `free` the memory you allocate when it is no longer needed `:)`

Answer (score 0):

The way you are attempting right now is not going to work since `buffer` is on the stack for that function and no longer exists once the function returns.

If you want to return an array from a function, you can either declare it to be `static`, so it goes in the process’ data section rather than on the stack, or allocate it with `malloc(100)`, and later `free` it in the calling code when you’re done with it.